# How to exclude nodes from a match if they have a relationship with a certain parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've created some nodes that describe a process. Using pretty standard best practices it looks something like this:

```
(process:Process)-[:FIRST_STEP {parent:id(process)}]->(step1:Step)-[:NEXT {parent:id(process)}]->etc.
```

So it's a parent node of the Process type followed by a bunch of steps each of the step type, and each relationship proceeding from the parent has a property of parent with the id of the parent process.

This is done so that a step could be included in multiple processes, and works pretty well.

Now I need to delete a process and all of its steps. What I want to avoid is deleting any child step of the parent that belongs in another process's string of steps.

My first step is:

```
match(p:Process)-[rel:FIRST_STEP | :NEXT* {parent:id(p)}]->(step)
where id(p) = 1234
return p, step
```

This will return the Process and all the steps. Now I want to not return any steps that are spoken for by other Processes. This is what I have, but it's not working and I could use any ideas:

```
match(p:Process)-[rel:FIRST_STEP | :NEXT* {parent:id(p)}]->(step)
where id(p) = 1234
and not exists(
 (step)<-[otherrelation:FIRST_STEP|NEXT]-() WHERE otherrelation.parent <> id(p)
)
```

The WHERE clause in the exists() section blows it up and I'm not finding documentation on how to do this.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that patterns in `EXISTS()` and `NOT EXISTS()` can't be used to introduce new variables, like your `otherRelation`.

In the absence of an `EXCLUDE MATCH` clause, we have to get by with an `OPTIONAL MATCH` on the pattern we don't want, then prune matches where the matched pattern exists.

```
MATCH(p:Process)-[rel:FIRST_STEP | :NEXT* {parent:id(p)}]->(step) 
WHERE id(p) = 1234
WITH p, rel, step
OPTIONAL MATCH (step)<-[otherrelation:FIRST_STEP|NEXT]-() 
WHERE otherrelation.parent <> id(p)
WITH p, rel, step
WHERE otherrelation IS NULL
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That's way better than what I ended up doing, which was much more blunt force. Optional match is something I wasn't seeing the subtlety of. I'd upvote you more but my reputation is still too low.